# Desktop streaming to a html video tag

Tags: html, node.js, google-chrome-extension, websocket

I'm trying to make a website where a user can share their screen to other users. I've made a chrome extension that uses `navigator.webkitGetUserMedia` to get the screen of a user who pushes a button. Currently I'm only using `URL.createObjectUrl(stream)` (where the stream is the stream I got from `webkitGetUserMedia`) to get a BLOB url, I then set a video tag's `src` equals this url. Obviously this only displays the screen to the user who pushed the button. I am however wondering how I can make it so that all the users see the stream.

I have tried to send the URL to the other users via socket.io, but they can't access the BLOB.

Any ideas to how I make this work?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebRTC